# How to Exit Out of Loop Instance - C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Let's say I have a `for` loop and an array of ints. In my `for` loop, I say `if (array[i] == 2)` then I want to skip all the rest of the `for` loop and go to the next instance. now I can't use the `break` keyword as that will exit out of the entire loop.

What can I use to exit out of only one instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use continue to go to the next iteration:

```
if (array[i] == 2) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks Man, just what I was looking for!

Comment: I’m glad I could help you. If it worked, you might consider to flag the answer as accepted, so that if anyone else need the same, knows that this is correct.

Comment: sorry i was but i said i had to wait 10 minutes after i ask a question but i forgot to come back 